# when RadEditor -Telerik toolbarmode set to Default issue in chrome browser

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, telerik, radeditor

Am using RadEditor -Telerik .

when Toolbarmode is set to Default tools are not displaying in chrome browser where as working fine in IE and firefox .

I am not getting wats going on why this issue in chrome.

Here is my code

```
   Private Function GetNewEditorControl(ByVal sField As String, ByVal iWidth As Integer, _
                                        ByVal iHeight As Integer, ByVal bUnique As Boolean, ByVal iColFldWidth As Integer, _
                                        ByVal iColSpan As Integer) As Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor
    Dim sProc As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name & "::" & System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name

    Dim iUltimateWidth As Integer
    Select Case iWidth
        Case 0
            iUltimateWidth = iColFldWidth
            If iColSpan > 1 Then iUltimateWidth = iUltimateWidth + ((iColSpan - 1) * 4)
        Case Else
            iUltimateWidth = iWidth
    End Select

    Dim oEditor As New Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor()
    oEditor.ID = sField
    If bUnique = False Then oEditor.ID = sField & "[" & GetNextSeqNo.ToString & "]"
    oEditor.Height = iHeight * 20
    oEditor.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(iUltimateWidth)

    SetEditorProperties(oEditor)

    Return oEditor

End Function

'V_T:2/23/2015 MMR Change
Private Sub SetEditorProperties(ByVal oEditor As Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)

    oEditor.ToolbarMode = EditorToolbarMode.Default    
    oEditor.EditModes = EditModes.Design
    oEditor.NewLineMode = EditorNewLineModes.Br

    Dim uploadImages As String() = New String() {"~/Temp/MMRImages"}

    oEditor.ImageManager.ViewPaths = uploadImages
    oEditor.ImageManager.UploadPaths = uploadImages
    oEditor.ImageManager.MaxUploadFileSize = 2000000
    oEditor.ImageManager.AllowMultipleSelection = False
    oEditor.ImageManager.EnableAsyncUpload = True
    oEditor.ImageManager.EnableImageEditor = False

    oEditor.EnsureToolsFileLoaded()

    'to remove the Image context menu in the editor content area
    Dim imgTag As Telerik.Web.UI.EditorContextMenu = oEditor.ContextMenus.FindByTagName("IMG")
    imgTag.Enabled = False
```

please help me through this .

Comment: Finnaly i got with this <style type="text/css">
 .Default.reToolbarWrapper
 {
 height: 80px !important;
 }
 </style>

Comment: THere are some minimal dimensions the editor must have in order to show up properly, make sure the height is sufficient (i.e., try increasing it for the test).

Comment: I have a problem here by increasing the height of tool bar ..Rad editor content area height is increasing i.e coming out of rad editor fixed height this is also only in chrome ..

Comment: how to set content area height pragmatically in Vb.net ..

Comment: You can't. The control calculates its dimensions via JS when it renders. You can read more about it here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-appearance-issues-with-initially-hidden-editor.html.
Also, try the Lighweight RenderMode to see if it improves the situation.
In general, try to have at least 200px height and 400px width or something. The minimal size depends on the tools you have enabled.